# Export 'INSERTS' from H2

Tags: spring, h2, in-memory-database

Is there any option to get all inserts from h2 before I killed app ? There is probably some lifecycle hook on shutdown in spring boot, but I am not really sure if there is any option to get ' dump of inserts'.

Comment: You mean something like [`SCRIPT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script)?

Comment: Yeap, with all inserts.

Comment: So why doesn't SCRIPT work for you?